# Cannot add eventListener to img elements before they are created

Tags: javascript

I have a blank page, if you dblclick anywhere, an image will fade in where the dblclick event happened. This works fine.

I have a function appear which can be called to fade in elements or fade out, depending on parameter passed into it. I call that from the getItOut function, passing eventTarget as first parameter.

But, now I want a functionality to remove the images on click(our other event, does not really matter).

I try this:

```
var allImages = []; // initializing array to iterate over img node list
var displayedImages = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG'); get img node list
allImages.push(displayedImages); // push the displayed imgs to the array

// here I want to run this function by iterating with forEach over the array
allImages.forEach(function(el) {el.addEventListener('click', getItOut)}); // getting type error, el.addEventListener is not a function


function getItOut(event){ // this should be called during the above forEach iteration
var getOut = event.target;
appear(getOut, 100, -5, 40);

}
```

Here is the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/RqMxex

I have commented out the above, as the thrown error would not let anything run.

What am I doing wrong here? Should I check if an img element exists in the DOM at some place?

Comment: are you sure the line `allImages.push(displayedImages);` works as intended? wouldn't it just push entire array onto the first element of allImages variable?

Comment: Your codepen does not demonstrate the problem, and your question does not even mention the error message. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: HM, not sure why you say that, all the above is in the question

Comment: @ptts What is the error message?

Comment: @melpomene, getting type error, el.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski, that is a good point, it does something else though, it pushes the whole collection into a new index every time, not just into the first one, this is weird.Both are no good.

Comment: @ptts What's the actual, complete error message?

Comment: @melpomene
Uncaught TypeError: el.addEventListener is not a function
    at pen.js:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pen.js:7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are pushing Images as HTMLCollection not a DOM element to allImages and when you iterate through you can't bind EventListener to a Collection.

`allImages.push(displayedImages);` // result is [HTMLCollection(1)]

Also wait for images or DOM content to load then add `eventlistener`

It works.[I created a jsfiddle test it in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Talavoock/fesp7a3L/6/)

Code snippet:

```js
var images = ['//unsplash.it/500/500', '//unsplash.it/400/500','//unsplash.it/500/300'];


function getItOut(event){
 var getOut = event.target;
 appear(getOut, 100, -5, 40);
 //Fixing bug for click same position of disappeared image
 // to not appear again 
 // and fix fadeOut opacity
 var timerId = setInterval(function () {
     const opacity = Number(getOut.style.opacity);
   if(opacity == 0) {
   getOut.parentNode.removeChild(getOut);
    clearInterval(timerId);
   }
}, 40)
 
}


document.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
  var currentImg;
  var ix = event.clientX;     // Get the coordinates
var iy = event.clientY; 
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", images[0]);
    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
    x.setAttribute("height", "228");
    x.style.position="absolute";
   x.style.top= iy + 'px';
  x.style.left= ix + 'px';
  x.style.opacity = 0.1;
    document.body.appendChild(x);
 x.addEventListener('click', getItOut)
  //x.classList.add("fadeIn");
  var ix = "";
  var iy = "";
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
  appear(x, 0, 5, 40);
  

});



function appear(elm, i, step, speed){
    var t_o;
    //initial opacity
    i = i || 0;
    //opacity increment
    step = step || 5;
    //time between opacity increments in ms
    speed = speed || 50; 

    t_o = setInterval(function(){
        //get opacity in decimals
        var opacity = i / 100;
        //set the next opacity step
        i = i + step; 
        if(opacity > 1 || opacity < 0){
            clearInterval(t_o);
            //if 1-opaque or 0-transparent, stop
            return; 
        }
        //real browsers
        elm.style.opacity = opacity;
        //IE
        elm.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity*100 + ')';
    
    }, speed);
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: displayedImages is not defined

Comment: @Hangaaw That's what I've been testing. The images don't disappear.

Comment: @melpomene okey i changed some code that was my mistake. when you create image with double click it means that image is displayed so on when you create then you can bind event listener to it i moved the listener to `dbclick handler`. now if you try same **fiddlejs example** it is working well.

Comment: The jsfiddle example is unchanged. It's still the old code.

Comment: Sorry [Here is the new one](https://jsfiddle.net/Talavoock/fesp7a3L/6/) and i updated the answer codes

Comment: This is brilliant and so elegant mate:-)

Comment: @ptts It's exactly what Unamata Sanatarai wrote 40 minutes ago.

Comment: no looping, straight to the point, avoiding all the html collection issues:-)

Comment: @melpomene that was jquery and now he doesn't need for document to be ready because he is making images by double clicking not loading from document. so this is different.

Comment: @melpomene, well true, but thsi guy went and created a js solution. Me personally, I have learned something new and enlightening from this answer, the jQuery solution was a known abstraction which I did not understand why exactly it worked, until now.

Comment: @Hangaaw The jQuery code was an example of solution #2. This is solution #1 ("wait for the elements to be created").

Comment: @ptts but there is a problem in this code when you click on any images you are just disappearing by opacity. so if click the same position in document the image will appear and then auto disappear.you can remove it from DOM if you want to completely remove it.

Comment: @Hangaaw, yes, I suppose doing event.taget.style.display = "none" in the fn getItOut would fix that.
Or how would you delete it from the DOM

Comment: @ptts you can remove it this way. put this code `this.parentNode.removeChild(this) ` in  getItOut function after `appear` function call.

Comment: @Hangaaw, this removes them without a fadeout effect , tough.

Comment: @ptts [here is an option](https://jsfiddle.net/Talavoock/fesp7a3L/24/) for this situation. if you look at my code i changed the `getItOut` method implementation. added a `setInterval` to look for  `opacity` and when the `opacity` reaches 0 then remove it in DOM and clearing interval

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes!

You CANNOT hook a listener to something, that does not exist.

There are 2 ways to go about it.

1. Wait for the elements to be created (document.ready)
2. Hook your listener to the document, and then parse to see what has been clicked. jQuery has got you covered: `$(document).on('EVENT', 'SELECTOR', function(){})`

Comment: Thanks, I know about that, I was afraid that this is  the issue. but I want/need a non jQuery solution. There should be a way to only run the code after something like if(img)

Comment: Another thing is , the images are not created on domConentLoaded or doc ready, but only after a dblclick event

Comment: @ptts This answer still applies. You can either define a click handler in your `dblclick` handler where you create the `img` (which you haven't shown in your question, grr), or define a global click handler that inspects its target element to decide what to do (which you can do without jQuery).